# How can i find the dimensions of a simple rectangle in an image?

Tags: c++, image, sfml

How can i find rectangles in a bitmap image

[Image i'm testing with, white is the origin and grey are walls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1hoa.png), [This is what most will look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tC7Su.png)I'm trying to read an image and place walls in a 2d space depending on the colours of the pixels, using c++ and sfml. In the image, there's a rectangle shape of pixels. I first tried adding a square wall for each pixel, but this is obviously an ineffective solution. I then tried creating rows of longer rectangles. This works ok but it still isn't optimal. How can i find the dimensions of this rectangle given pixel positions and colours so i'm able to use one wall shape?

Comment: you are going to need to be clearer about the statement of the problem you need to solve ... you want to extract the dimensions of the white and gray rectangles given the image? Is it given that the image will only contain non-overlapping rectangles of various colors against a black background?

Comment: You draw the image from data in your program right? If so don't use the image, use the data in your program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest implementing a contour tracing algorithm.

1. This algorithm has an invariant that you are always in an empty cell, with a non-empty cell on your right.  Begin in any such cell and begin a contour line segment where the green segment is indicated. 
   [image: default state]
2. You are in the pixel with the magenta arrow, facing in that direction.  By examining the two pixels ahead, there are only 4 cases.
3. If you are back to where you started, then close the contour (ignore this check the first time)
4. If the cell ahead is non-empty, conclude the line segment at the current point and begin a new one.  Turn left and repeat (goto 2) *Note there is a non-empty cell on your right.* 
   [image: turn left]
5. If the cell ahead is empty and the cell to its right is non-empty, move forward and repeat. Do not add a line segment vertex, just keep extending the current line segment.  Then repeat (goto 2).  *Note that there is a non-empty cell on your right.* 
   [image: move forward]
6. If the cell ahead is empty and the cell to its right is empty, conclude the current line segment, turn right and repeat (goto 2). *Note that there is a non-empty cell on your right.*
   [image: turn right]
7. If the cell ahead is non-empty and the cell to its right is empty, then you may choose (by your own convention) to interpret this as a left turn or right turn (as in step 4 or step 6) Depending on whether you think that shapes that touch only at a corner are connected or not.  
   [image: turn left (alt)] [image: turn right (alt)]

When this algorithm concludes, you will have a set of line segments that trace the contour of the shape that you can add as vector/polygonal geometry into your scene.

Comment: Thank you very much. These seems to be what I'm looking for.